# Select com dois context em entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Eu preciso fazer uma comparação, de dois bancos de dados, preciso trazer os emails que não existe no outro banco.
Tentei fazer desta forma:

```
var email = _contextVO.Usuarios.Where(x => x.Ativo == true && !_userManager.Users.Where(a => a.Email == x.Email).Any()).ToListAsync();
```

Porém ele me retorna este erro:

> Cannot use multiple DbContext instances within a single query execution. Ensure the query uses a single context instance

Pensei em separar, mas não consegui comparar! Eu não consigo trabalhar desta forma com dois context ? Como posso contornar este problema. Pois vou precisar inserir os dados do Banco1 para o Banco2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, pra cada contexto é preciso trazer uma lista, e só depois fazer as comparações;

Se tivesse todos os atributos dessas classes, poderia fazer uma consulta melhor, com o que foi dado, ficaria assim:

```
//buscando os dados em _contextVO
var Lista_Usuarios = (from u in _contextVO.Usuarios
            Where(u.Ativo)
            select u).toList();

//buscando os dados em _userManager          
var Lista_2 = (from u in _userManager.Users).toList();
//comparando
var Lista_Filtrada  = Lista_Usuarios.Where(w=>!Lista_2.contains(w.email));
```